# Sum up from line "A" to line "B" from a big file using awk

Tags: awk

```
aNumber|bNumber|startDate|timeZone|duration|currencyType|cost|
22677512549|778|2014-07-02 10:16:35.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|
22675557361|76457227|2014-07-02 10:16:38.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|
22677521277|778|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|
22676099496|77250331|2014-07-02 10:16:42.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|1.00|
22667222160|22667262389|2014-07-02 10:16:43.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|10.00|
22665799922|70110055|2014-07-02 10:16:45.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|20.00|
22676239633|433|2014-07-02 10:16:48.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|0.00|
22677277255|76919167|2014-07-02 10:16:51.000|NULL|NULL|localCurrency|1.00|
```

This is the input (sample of million of line) i have in csv file.
I want to sum up duration based on date.
My concern is i want to sum up first 1000000 lines
the awk program i'm using is:

test.awk

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" } 
NR>1 && NR<=1000000 
FNR == 1{ next } 
{ 
sub(/ .*/,"",$3) 
key=sprintf("%10s",$3)
duration[key] += $5 } END {
printf "%-10s %16s,"dAccused","Duration"
for (i in duration) { 
    printf "%-4s %16.2f i,duration[i]  
}}
```

i run my script as

```
$awk -f test.awk 'file'
```

The input i have doesn't condsidered my condition  NR>1 && NR<=1000000

ANY SUGGESTION? PLEASE!

Comment: `NR>1 && NR<=1000000 FNR == 1` you missed `;` between those assuming that was two tests. `NR>1 && NR<=1000000; FNR == 1` What were you trying to have that condition control exactly? The block with the `sub` in it?

Comment: Wow! i got back all the data from line 1 to 1000000 printed first in addition to my same past result

Comment: Try: `NR==1 {next} NR>1000000 {exit}`

Comment: Also try formatting your code better: each condition-action pair should start on a new line

Comment: You have to use newlines or semicolons to separate statements in awk.

Comment: Missing close brace for the END block

Comment: @EdMorton, at least he didn't post a million and one lines!

Comment: lol sorry guys. I think it's more clear now

Comment: You right @EdMorton! Hope more people will look at it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" } 
1 < NR && NR <= 1000000 { 
    sub(/ .*/, "", $3) 
    key = sprintf("%10s",$3)
    duration[key] += $5 
} 
END {
    printf "%-10s %16s\n", "dAccused", "Duration"
    for (i in duration) { 
        printf "%-4s %16.2f i,duration[i]  
    }
}
```

A lot of errors become obvious with proper indentation.

The reason you saw 1,000,000 lines was due to this:

```
NR>1 && NR<=1000000
```

That is a condition with no action block. The default action is to print the current record if the condition is true. That's why you see a lot of awk one-liners end with the number `1`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @glennjackman! It's exactly what i was looking for. I have something i would like to ask, do you think the script will read all the line ( read all the rows of the input file) before returning the result or as soon as it reached row 1,000,000 the result will be displayed ?

Comment: You don't start printing until the END block. awk doesn't get to the END block until it's read all the input. If you want to skip all the lines after 1,000,000, add `NR > 1000000 {exit}`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any expected output and your duration field is always NULL so it's still not clear what you really want output, but this is probably the right approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "|" }
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<NF;i++) f[$i] = i; next }
{
    sub(/ .*/,"",$(f["startDate"]))
    sum[$(f["startDate"])] += $(f["duration"])
}
NR==1000000 { exit }
END { for (date in sum) print date, sum[date] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2014-07-02 0
```

Instead of discarding your header line, it uses it to create an array `f[]` that maps the field names to their order in each line so instead of having to hard-code that duration is field 4 (or whatever) you just reference it as `$(f["duration"])`.

Any time your input file has a header line, don't discard it - use it so your script is not coupled to the order of fields in your input file.